# Receive email from users in my gmail account when user submit the contact form in laravel in live server

Tags: laravel, email, cpanel

I am using laravel 7. I want to receive email from user in my gmail account when user submit the contact form in live server.
My .env

```html
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mygmail
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

My controller

```html
public function saveContact(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'contact_no' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required',
    ]);

    $contact = new Contact();
    $contact->name = $request->name;
    $contact->email = $request->email;
    $contact->contact_no = $request->contact_no;
    $contact->message = $request->message;
    $contact->save();

    $data = array(
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'phone' => $request->contact_no,
        'user_message' => $request->message
    );

    Mail::to('mygmail')
        ->send(new ContactMail($data));

    return back()->with('success', 'Thank you for contacting us.');
}
```

My contactMail.php

```html
public function build(Request $request)
{
    return $this->subject('New contact email')
        ->from($request->email)
        ->view('frontend.contact_email')
        ->with('data', $this->data);
}
```

I get this error, when i submit the form.

stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`domain.com' did not match expected CN=`smtp.gmail.com'

Comment: the environment file is set incorrectly.

Comment: What should be the environment file? I really need help.

Comment: change the mail port to 465

Comment: Yes i changed the mail port to 465.

Comment: try to clear php artisan config:clear

Comment: I clear config and not getting Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Network is unreachable)

Comment: If you are not using http instead of https then try to change your Mailport to 587. If not working then try to change your mail driver to sendmail  or Mail

Comment: I tried using sendmail and now I am getting Expected response code 220 but got an empty response.

Comment: Try to run `php artisan cache:clear;
php artisan config:cache;` If it doesn't work then set the Mail Driver back to smtp and clear cache and config again. Remember to restart your server each time you make changes in .env file

Comment: How to restart in live server(cpanel)?

Answer (score 1):

try this in yor .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=youraccount@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourapppassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
```

You must also enable access to less secure applications in your Google Acount

Comment: I have enabled it.

Comment: in your file `config/mail.php` in the option stream, set the ssl option `verify_peer => false`, `verify_peer_name => false`, and `'allow_self_signed' => true`. I'm based on: 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/stream-socket-enable-crypto-error-laravel

Comment: I am getting this now. Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Network is unreachable)

Comment: I am getting Expected response code 220 but got an empty response

Comment: do you try empty the cache: `php artisan config:cache`?

Answer (score 1):

Set the keys `verify_peer`, `verify_peer_name`, and `allow_self_signed` to solve the error.
You need to add the following of `\config\mail.php` :

```
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
    ],
],
```

Comment: Exactly where I should keep above code in mail.php?

Comment: Add this at bottom of your `config/mail.php`

Comment: I am getting Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Network is unreachable)

Comment: Do you get the same on `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl` & `MAIL_PORT=465`?

Comment: Yes I am using ssl and 465

Comment: I am getting Expected response code 220 but got an empty response